# plot a large number of axis objects using one command through a loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

Say I have a bunch of ax1,ax2,ax3... and I want to run them through a plotting function:

```
def plotxy(ax,x,y):
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    ax.plot(x,y)
```

(obviously simplified)

How would I repeat the command without doing:

```
plotxy(ax1,x,y)
plotxy(ax2,x,y)
...
plotxy(axn,x,y)
```

I'm sure there is a way to create a temp variable which holds the axn in a loop which could be just one line. Any ideas? It would greatly shorten my code as I've got heaps of things I need to plot with the same command but differing x & y and over multiple subplots.

I guess this is part of a large question of constructing variable names using a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)

for ax in axs.flat:
    plotxy(ax,x,y)
```

If you use `plt.subplot` or `plt.axes` you can create a list/array of axes by hand

Answer (score 1):

you can also use [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), `x` and `y` being name space variables and `axx` some iterable over your axes objects:

```
x = ...
y = ...

def plotxy(ax):
    ax.plot(x,y)

map(plotxy,axx)
```

Comment: `map` should not be used as a substitute for a loop.  In this case a loop is more appropriate, as `map` creates a list of results (`None`s in this case) which is never used, which is wasteful.  Also, a list comprehension should be preferred over `map`, but again, in this case I'd use neither.

Comment: @shx2 Well, technically `ax.plot` returns something, so `map` with `def plotxy(ax): return ax.plot(x,y)` would return a potentially useful list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something in your question, but why don't you just use a simple loop?

```
for ax in ( ax1, ax2, ..., axn ):
    plotxy(ax,x,y)
```

You can also avoid the explicit listing all variables:

```
axes = ( locals()['ax%d'%i] for i in range(1, n+1) )
for ax in axes:
    plotxy(ax,x,y)
```

Comment: What do you mean? all the variables in your question are named `"ax%d"%i`

Comment: I meant if my variable was called plot1ax1 and I wanted to loop over the number in plot i.e. plot1ax1,plot2ax1 etc.

Comment: The loop with `'ax%d'%i` constructs the names of the variables.  If your variables are named `plot?ax1`, you can replace `'ax%d'%i` with `'plot%dax1'%i`, or `'plot%dax%d'%(i,j)` for 2D naming convention...

Comment: Also I think there is an error up above with your [ not closing.